# Race Condition in Sagemaker Batch Transform Job

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

We are facing this bug in our production environment. I have been looking for a solution for a while and I cannot seem to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

We are using Sagemaker Batch Transform to perform inference on our machine learning models. Each job is supposed to create one instance using a docker image from our ECR container. This job then consumes a payload and starts processing it using a pytorch script. When the job is done, the script calls an API to store the results.

The **issue** is that when we check the cloud watch logs for a SINGLE job, we see that it is repeated. After the job is repeated multiple times, the individual instances of the same job may or may not finish and the whole operation returns with an error.

Basically, we see the following issue in our cloud watch logs and cannot seem to figure out what is causing this:

```
2022-04-24 19:41:47,865 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Starting to Process Task: 12345678-abcd-1234-efgh-123456ab12c3
...
[The job is running and printing logs]
...
[There is no error but the job doesn't seem to run anymore, the same job seems to roll back again]
...
2022-04-24 19:52:09,522 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Starting to Process Task: 12345678-abcd-1234-efgh-123456ab12c3
...
[The job is running and printing logs]
...
[There is no error but the job doesn't seem to run anymore, the same job seems to roll back again]
...
2022-04-24 20:12:11,834 [INFO ] W-model-1-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Starting to Process Task: 12345678-abcd-1234-efgh-123456ab12c3
...
[The job is running and printing logs]
...
[There are no errors but the cloud watch logs stop here. Sagemaker returns an error to the client.]
```

The following sample code is what we are using to run the jobs:

```
def inference_batch(self):
    batch_input = f"s3://{self.cnf.SAGEMAKER_BUCKET}/batch-input/batch.csv"
    batch_output = f"s3://{self.cnf.SAGEMAKER_BUCKET}/batch-output/"
    job_name = f"{self.cnf.SAGEMAKER_MODEL}-{str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%m-%S'))}"

    transform_input = {
        'DataSource': {
            'S3DataSource': {
                'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
                'S3Uri': batch_input
            }
        },
        'ContentType': 'text/csv',
        'SplitType': 'Line',
    }

    transform_output = {
        'S3OutputPath': batch_output
    }

    transform_resources = {
        'InstanceType': self.cnf.SAGEMAKER_BATCH_INSTANCE,
        'InstanceCount': 1
    }
    
    # self.sm_boto_client is an instance of boto3.Session(region_name="some-region).client("sagemaker")
    self.sm_boto_client.create_transform_job(
        TransformJobName=job_name,
        ModelName=self.cnf.SAGEMAKER_MODEL,
        TransformInput=transform_input,
        TransformOutput=transform_output,
        TransformResources=transform_resources
    )

    status = self.sm_boto_client.describe_transform_job(TransformJobName=job_name)
    print(f'Executing transform job {job_name}...')
    while status['TransformJobStatus'] == 'InProgress':
        time.sleep(5)
        status = self.sm_boto_client.describe_transform_job(TransformJobName=job_name)

    if status['TransformJobStatus'] == 'Completed':
        print(f'Batch transform job {job_name} successfully completed.')
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Batch transform job {job_name} failed.')
```